# Stretching ConstraintLayout and its content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

I built a fragment (with ConstraintLayout), which looks like this:
[Fragment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxN87.png)
I would like to reuse it, for example load it (add to fragmentManager) to an Activity's "fragment holder", but if this holder is too small, the images will cover each other.
See this:
[Image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukAE4.jpg)
So, the images won't resize... Is there any solution to achieve the automatic resizing?

Thanks,
Zoltan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Place each of your `ImageViews` in their own `ConstraintLayout`. The `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the `ImageViews` should be `wrap_content`. The `layout_width` and `layout_height` of their parent `ConstraintViews` should be `match_parent` and `wrap_content` respectively.

Anchor the left `ConstraintView` to the top and start of the parent, and the right `ConstraintView` to the top and end using `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`, `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf`, and `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf`.

Also add the margins to the parent `ConstraintViews` using `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginLeft` for the left; `layout_marginTop` and `layout_marginRight` for the right.

Next, create a `vertical` `Guideline` as a child of your fragment. Set its `layout_constraintGuide_percent` to `0.5`. Give it an `id` of `@+id/guideline`.

Set the left `ConstraintView's` `layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf` to `@+id/guideline`, and the right `ConstraintView's` `layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf` to `@+id/guideline` as well.

This should scale the `ImageViews` sizes down if the fragment is not that wide.

If you want there to be a minimum gap between the two images, you can add `layout_marginRight` to the left `ConstraintView`, and `layout_marginLeft` to the right `ConstraintView`. Setting each to `2dp` would give a minimum gap of `4dp`.

Here is an example layout file. Edit the container `ConstraintLayout's` `layout_width` to see it in action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="#333333">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="#00FF00">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Enough Room]
[image: Not Enough Room]

Comment: Nice approach!
I tried to simplify my real problem, so I said I have two images, but I have four... In one line and I have 4 line... So I have 16 images. :)

Comment: (suddenly Enter posted my comment...) 
So, your solution looks great, but I couldn't use to solve my real problem... :(
Evenmore, I experienced a strange Android Studio issue:
In text mode I write 'match_parent' to my image, then I click on Design, then back to Text and the Studio replace it to a fix value! :O Why?

Comment: ConstraintLayout's purpose is to avoid multiple nested layouts, so I don't like the proposed solution with 4 ConstraintLayouts. Could be probably achieved by a single ConstraintLayout together with the "matching constraints" width.